# Problem with linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am probably missing something obvious, but I am getting a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' null error in my Linq to xml query.

Here is a sample of the xml

```
<airport>
  <station>
  <city>Rutland</city>
  <state>VT</state>
  <country>US</country>
  <icao>KRUT</icao>
  <lat>43.52999878</lat>
  <lon>-72.94999695</lon>
  </station>
</airport>
```

and here is my query

```
XDocument geoLocation = XDocument.Load("myTestGeo.xml");

            var currLocation = from geo in geoLocation.Descendants("airport")
                              select new
                              {
                                  City = geo.Element("city").Value,
                                  State = geo.Element("state").Value,
                                  Country = geo.Element("country").Value,
                                  Station = geo.Element("icao").Value
                                  Lat = geo.Element("lat").Value,
                                  Lon = geo.Element("lon").Value
                              };
```

I have been looking at this all day and tried lots of things, but no luck. Can someone help this dense programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

city and all the other values are inside station and are not direct descendants of airport.

Perhaps some indentation sheds some light into the issue.

```
<airport>
  <station>
    <city>Rutland</city>
    <state>VT</state>
    <country>US</country>
    <icao>KRUT</icao>
    <lat>43.52999878</lat>
    <lon>-72.94999695</lon>
  </station>
</airport>
```

This would probably work:

```
XDocument geoLocation = XDocument.Load("myTestGeo.xml");

var currLocation = from geo in geoLocation.Descendants("station")
                  select new
                  {
                      City = geo.Element("city").Value,
                      State = geo.Element("state").Value,
                      Country = geo.Element("country").Value,
                      Station = geo.Element("icao").Value
                      Lat = geo.Element("lat").Value,
                      Lon = geo.Element("lon").Value
                  };
```

Comment: I see that, but if I query on station I get the same null error.

Comment: I do not have .net framework with linq so I cannot test for myself. See http://www.linqhelp.com/linq-tutorials/linq-to-xml-displaying-and-filtering-data-from-xml-file-in-c/ for and example that is very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And are you sure that `myTestGeo.xml` has the XML that you pointed out on the example?

Comment: It is a xml file from weather underground, and there are other nodes below this one, but I have used linq to xml to read xml files before this. The nodes below the airport mode are <station></station> also but I am not interested those. If you want I will post a more complete fragment of the file.

Answer (score 0):

`Descendants()` gives all elements at any level below the current node whereas `Element()` only looks at direct children of the current node. As all the values you request with the `Element()` call are children of `station` and not `airport`, the calls to `Element()` return no objects. Dereferencing them with `.Value` leads to the exception.

If you change your query to the following, it should work:

```
XDocument geoLocation = XDocument.Load("myTestGeo.xml");

var currLocation = from geo in geoLocation.Descendants("station")
                   select new
                   {
                       City = geo.Element("city").Value,
                       State = geo.Element("state").Value,
                       Country = geo.Element("country").Value,
                       Station = geo.Element("icao").Value
                       Lat = geo.Element("lat").Value,
                       Lon = geo.Element("lon").Value
                   };
```